# wkhtmltopdf not giving exact result for google search

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, google-search

**wkhtmltopdf** not giving exact pdf of google search
wkhtmltopdf Command

```
wkhtmltopdf toc --javascript-delay 5000 --load-error-handling ignore "https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-beta&hs=1re&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=fflb&q=height+of+lionel+messi&oq=height+of+lionell&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i13l2j0i13i30.3477969.3479300.0.3480775.7.7.0.0.0.0.233.1161.2j1j4.7.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.8wCY6CBhpqY" google.pdf
```

Try [**google search**](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-beta&hs=1re&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&q=height%20of%20lionel%20messi&oq=height%20of%20lionell&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i13l2j0i13i30.3477969.3479300.0.3480775.7.7.0.0.0.0.233.1161.2j1j4.7.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.8wCY6CBhpqY)

In that **1.69m** Which comes under google search box not displayed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer myself, In case anyone come through same problem in future
Problem was I was not sending 'User-Agent'

**TRY THIS**

```
wkhtmltopdf --custom-header "User-Agent" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1" --custom-header-propagation "https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-beta&hs=1re&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=fflb&q=height+of+lionel+messi&oq=height+of+lionell&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i13l2j0i13i30.3477969.3479300.0.3480775.7.7.0.0.0.0.233.1161.2j1j4.7.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.8wCY6CBhpqY" google.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below command it will generate desktop version:

```
wkhtmltopdf --viewport-size 1280x1024 --orientation Landscape http://site_name.com file_name.pdf
```